# Prove Herschel graph is nonhamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-path

Let us denote by $c(G)$ the number of components of graph $G$.

Theory: For a hamiltonain graph we have $c(G-S)\leq|S|$ for any set $S$ of vertices of $G$.

How can I show that Herschel graph is nonhamiltonian using this theory?
[image: Herschel graph]

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this theory can be used to prove that the Herschel graph is non-Hamiltonian.

Let us remove three vertices of this graph lying on its vertical axis of symmetry. We obtain a new graph of two components, each component is a claw ($K_{1,3}$).

Now delete the central vertices of the claws. We will get $6$ of isolated vertices, but we have removed only $5$ of vertices.

Comment: Another observation to show the same result: The graph is bipartite and has an odd number of vertices.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is a solution I have always known, and I think the author of the question knows this solution too.